# Convert form data to JSON file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I have a project in `Node JS` in which I have a `form` to add new users.

How can I view this information in `JSON` format?

These are the data that I see:

```
name   age   country   city
------------------------------
user1   22    Spain    Madrid      button{View JSON}
```

When I press the 'View JSON' button, the following must be displayed below the table:

```
[
   "id": 1,
   "name": "user1",
   "age": 22,
   "country": "Spain" {
      "city":"Madrid"
   }
]
```

**My problem**: how can I create a function that performs this conversion? How do I call the function from `index.ejs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleared and merged the codes. And I created a new endpoint as `/export` to export the data as CSV file. I couldn't test it so let me know if it doesn't work.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', './src/views');

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    const db = await mongoDB();

    const person = await db.collection('person').find().toArray();

    res.render('index.ejs', { person: person })
})

app.get('/export', async (req, res) => {

    await convertCSV();

    res.status(200).send( { success: 1 });
})

app.post('/person', async (req, res) => {

    res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
    console.log(`server: http://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}`);
})


const mongoDB = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
        MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
            .then(client => {
                const db = client.db('users')
                resolve(db);


            })
            .catch(error => reject(error))
    });
}


const convertCSV = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const converter = require("json-2-csv");
        const fetch = require("node-fetch");
        const fs = require("fs");
        const flatten = require('flat');
    
        const maxRecords = 10;
    
        const getJson = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`http://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/users.json`);
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        };
    
        const convertToCSV = async () => {
            const json = await getJson();
            let keys = Object.keys(flatten(json[0]));
            let options = {
                keys: keys
            };
            converter.json2csv(json, json2csvCallback, options);
        };
    
        let json2csvCallback = function (err, csv) {
            if (err) throw err;
            const headers = csv.split('\n').slice(0, 1);
            const records = csv.split('\n').slice(0,);
            for (let i = 1; i < records.length; i = i + maxRecords) {
                let dataOut = headers.concat(records.slice(i, i + 3)).join('\n');
                let id = Math.floor(i / maxRecords) + 1;
                fs.writeFileSync('data' + id + '.csv', dataOut)
            }
        };
    
        await convertToCSV();
        resolve();
    })
}
```

However, it is not a good practice at all to using controller, index and route in the same file. A better approach would be to create routes, controllers folders and put the codes in a more orderly form.

Something like this (You can find better ones of course mine is just advice):

```
 - index.js
 - router.js (A router to manage your endpoints)
 - controllers (Controller when you call the endpoint)
  -> export.controller.js
  -> person.controller.js
 - routes (Endpoints)
  -> export.route.js
  -> person.route.js
 - helpers
  -> databaseHandler.js (Database connection handler)
```

Comment: I have been modifying the folder structure to leave it as you say separately. On the other hand, the export CSV button does not work for me, I have called the convertCSV () function in the html but I can't get it to enter

Comment: And html does not read the variables, I have added a function in the index: ``function test() {
  console.log('view JSON');
}`` and in the html: ``<button id="viewJson" onclick="test()">View JSON</button>``, but it does not enter

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not know much about HTML-nodejs communication. But, It's interesting that the javascript you added doesn't work. Are you sure you are correctly importing javascript file?

Comment: I have updated the question to go by parts because I cannot execute the complete code